# Getting "No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Windows'" error when trying Windows Authetication

Tags: identityserver4, windows-authentication

I want to enable Windows Authentication for my IdentityServer hosted by IIS (in process). The doc from IdentityServer4 stated that "You trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync on the Windows scheme" but it does say where and how. I was assuming it is in the Login function of the AccountController but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the error I am getting when running my IdentityServer
[image]

But to my knowledge, I had registered the authentication for Windows scheme. Here is the ConfigurtionServices and Confiuration functions of the Startup.cs for the identityserver:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; 
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    var connstr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connstr));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
    })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connstr,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

    // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    //services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(
    //    new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "certs", "IdentityServer4Auth.pfx")));

    // configures IIS in-proc settings
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });

    // for Windows authentication 
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }

    // use MVC
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    // use MVC
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

As you can see the very last line in ConfigurationServices function, **I registered authentication handler for Windows by calling services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)**.

Here is the Login function in the AccountController.cs, in which I call ChallengeWindowsAsync - **I thought this is how the IdentityServer4 Doc suggested to do but I am not sure. If it is not the right way, how should I correct it?**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync
    await ChallengeWindowsAsync(returnUrl);

    // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
    {
        // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
        return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { scheme = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

And here is the ChallengeWindowsAsync function

```
private async Task<IActionResult> ChallengeWindowsAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    // see if windows auth has already been requested and succeeded
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows");
    if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
    {
        // we will issue the external cookie and then redirect the
        // user back to the external callback, in essence, treating windows
        // auth the same as any other external authentication mechanism
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", "Windows" },
            }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Windows");

        // the sid is a good sub value
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));

        // the account name is the closest we have to a display name
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

        // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
        var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

        // translate group SIDs to display names
        var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
        id.AddClaims(roles);


        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
            props);
        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }
    else
    {
        // trigger windows auth
        // since windows auth don't support the redirect uri,
        // this URL is re-triggered when we call challenge
        return Challenge("Windows");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you have gone through the ID4 sample code and tried to implement it in your app. It would be great if you add your first cut code, so I would be able to look into it and correct if anything is missing in it.

Comment: Just figured out my issue - the Enable Windows Authentication option in IIS manager was not set (I thought I set it but somehow got changed?). Anyhow, after finding that and reset, I was able to get a "Windows" button on my login page.